# Mkdocs is not found, but possible to uninstall on macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, mkdocs

My python versions are:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.9

python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
```

I have downloaded pip.

```
pip --version
pip 20.2.2 from /Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

pip3 --version
pip 20.2.2 from /Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

I need to download the `mkdocs` on my Mac. For that I run the command: `pip3 install mkdocs`. After running this command, I see that:

```
Successfully installed Jinja2-2.11.2 Markdown-3.2.2 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 PyYAML-5.3.1 click-7.1.2 future-0.18.2 joblib-0.16.0 livereload-2.6.3 lunr-0.5.8 mkdocs-1.1.2 nltk-3.5 regex-2020.7.14 tornado-6.0.4 tqdm-4.48.2
```

However, after I run the command `mkdocs --version`,  it says `zsh: command not found: mkdocs`. Whereas after I run `pip3 uninstall mkdocs` - it shows:

```
Found existing installation: mkdocs 1.1.2
Uninstalling mkdocs-1.1.2:
  Would remove:
    /Users/...
```

How do I install `mkdocs` so that I can run the needed `mkdocs serve`?

Comment: Add `/Users/lipa/Library/Python/3.8/bin` to `$PATH`

Comment: Thanks @phd I've just solved my problem. I needed to also install ```mkdocs-material``` and ```matplotlab``` and after run ```mkdocs serve``` in my project's root folder. The thing was, I had to use ```pip3``` in every command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article helped me a lot: https://jeannot-muller.com/code/mkdocs_on_macos/howto_install_mkdocs_on_macos/

I needed to also install `mkdocs-material` and `matplotlab` and after run mkdocs serve in my project's root folder. The thing was, I had to use `pip3` in every command.

```
sudo pip3 install mkdocs
sudo pip3 install mkdocs-material
sudo pip3 install matplotlib
```

in rootFolder/

```
mkdocs serve
```