# Error when trying to uninstall python package installed at a global level

Tags: python, pip

I accidentally installed enum34 globally on my mac. I run `pip uninstall enum34` and I get this massive error I don't understand

```
quantumcalzone@QuantumCalzones-MacBook-Pro ~ % pip uninstall enum34                                                                       
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Found existing installation: enum34 1.1.6
Uninstalling enum34-1.1.6:
  Would remove:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/enum
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/enum34-1.1.6-py2.7.egg-info
Proceed (y/n)? y
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/quantumcalzone/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 216, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/quantumcalzone/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 90, in run
    auto_confirm=options.yes, verbose=self.verbosity > 0,
  File "/Users/quantumcalzone/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 685, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
  File "/Users/quantumcalzone/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 394, in remove
    moved.stash(path)
  File "/Users/quantumcalzone/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 283, in stash
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Users/quantumcalzone/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 352, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 322, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 231, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/enum/LICENSE', '/private/var/folders/3b/39t55ql95xb4_2pdygrtvvwr0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-KLEMho/LICENSE', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/3b/39t55ql95xb4_2pdygrtvvwr0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-KLEMho/LICENSE'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/enum/__init__.py', '/private/var/folders/3b/39t55ql95xb4_2pdygrtvvwr0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-KLEMho/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/3b/39t55ql95xb4_2pdygrtvvwr0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-KLEMho/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/enum/test.py', '/private/var/folders/3b/39t55ql95xb4_2pdygrtvvwr0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-KLEMho/test.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/3b/39t55ql95xb4_2pdygrtvvwr0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-KLEMho/test.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/enum/README', '/private/var/folders/3b/39t55ql95xb4_2pdygrtvvwr0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-KLEMho/README', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/3b/39t55ql95xb4_2pdygrtvvwr0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-KLEMho/README'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/enum/__init__.pyc', '/private/var/folders/3b/39t55ql95xb4_2pdygrtvvwr0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-KLEMho/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/3b/39t55ql95xb4_2pdygrtvvwr0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-KLEMho/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/enum/doc/enum.pdf', '/private/var/folders/3b/39t55ql95xb4_2pdygrtvvwr0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-KLEMho/doc/enum.pdf', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/3b/39t55ql95xb4_2pdygrtvvwr0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-KLEMho/doc/enum.pdf'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/enum/doc/enum.rst', '/private/var/folders/3b/39t55ql95xb4_2pdygrtvvwr0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-KLEMho/doc/enum.rst', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/3b/39t55ql95xb4_2pdygrtvvwr0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-KLEMho/doc/enum.rst'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/enum/doc', '/private/var/folders/3b/39t55ql95xb4_2pdygrtvvwr0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-KLEMho/doc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/3b/39t55ql95xb4_2pdygrtvvwr0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-KLEMho/doc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/enum/test.pyc', '/private/var/folders/3b/39t55ql95xb4_2pdygrtvvwr0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-KLEMho/test.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/3b/39t55ql95xb4_2pdygrtvvwr0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-KLEMho/test.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/enum', '/private/var/folders/3b/39t55ql95xb4_2pdygrtvvwr0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-KLEMho', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/3b/39t55ql95xb4_2pdygrtvvwr0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-KLEMho'")]
```

Something about my python 2.7 license being not valid? I'm kind of clueless as to where to go from here and from my googling few have had the same issue and did not share what fixed it for them (if they even managed to).

Comment: Have you tried ```sudo pip uninstall enum34```? Or using ```pip3 uninstall enum34```?

Comment: Also, there is a new python version available: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-385/ 
You can upgrade it. ```python2``` and ```python3``` can co-exist, so there is no need in uninstalling ```python``` which can be even dangerous

Comment: @Lilya pip3 uninstall enum34 results in WARNING: Skipping enum34 as it is not installed.

Comment: I had the same issue with mkdocs. Please, read this question and the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63593069/mkdocs-is-not-found-but-possible-to-uninstall-on-macos